# A uniqueness property of several complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, several-complex-variables

according to this [website](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Uniqueness_properties_of_analytic_functions) the following theorem holds true for functions of several complex variables:

If $f(z)$ is an analytic function on a domain $D\subset C^n$ that vanishes in a real neighbourhood $U$ of a point $z_0=x_0+iy_0\in D$, that is, on a set $U=\{z=x+iy\in C^n:|x−x_0|<r,y=y_0\}$, then $f=0$ on $D$.

I couldn't find a reference for this theorem. Do you know a reference resp. an easy way to show this result?

Comment: If $f=u+iv$ the Cauchy-Riemann equations show that we can express the partials of $u, v$ in the $y$ directions by the ones in the $x$ directions which are zero by hypothesis at the points $(x,y_0)$; this implies that $f'=0$ on the set $U$; so we can repeat the reasoning and by induction, we get $f^{(n)}=0$ on $U$ for all $n$ etc

Comment: But wouldn't this show that $f$ is a constant function? Because as I understand it we show that $f^{(n)}=0$ for every $n \geq 1$ ...

Comment: that is of course what we want